# I search a tool to play with the quality and appearance of JPG photos to create a glitch effect

Tags: image-editor

I search for a tool with that I can "manipulate"/change,

- the quality of JPG files
- the appearance (glitch effect)
- changing some JPG peculiarities

My idea is to create cool JPG glitch effects and I want to save also a lot, really a lot, of storage (every byte is important).

Comment: Any picture editor should do. PS, Gimp, etc...